# Entity's equals() don't work properly in HashSet

Tags: java, hashset, equality

Could you give me an idea mhy equals() doesn't work properly in POJO, when its entity is added to HashSet? I checked and hascode() works correctly because returns the same hashcode for entities with equal fields. But nevertheless equal objects are added in HashSet. Please take a look at the code below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {
    private int accountID;
    private String accountNumber;
    private float amount;
    private String currency;
    private Client clientID;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    public int getAccountID() {
        return accountID;
    }

    public void setAccountID(int accountID) {
        this.accountID = accountID;
    }

    @Column(name = "account_number")
    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "amount")
    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }


    @Column(name = "currency")
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    public Client getClientID() {
        return clientID;
    }

    public void setClientID(Client clientID) {
        this.clientID = clientID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Account)) return false;

        Account account = (Account) o;

        if (Float.compare(account.amount, amount) != 0) return false;
        if (!accountNumber.equals(account.accountNumber)) return false;
        if (!clientID.equals(account.clientID)) return false;
        if (!currency.equals(account.currency)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = accountNumber.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (amount != +0.0f ? Float.floatToIntBits(amount) : 0);
        result = 31 * result + currency.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + clientID.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: One possible problem is that somehow entity changed after you put it in HashSet

Comment: Provide sample code which reproduces your issue.

Comment: does `Client` override `equals` and `hashcode` method?

Comment: check the `equals` and `hashCode` method of Client! make sure they work well!

Answer (score 1):

```
result = 31 * result + clientID.hashCode();
```

I think with this line of code the hashCode of the two objects are not the same.Try to remove this line and test

Answer (score 0):

thank you for pieces of advice but I realised what my mistake was. I didn't clarify that the application is used Hibernate for saving objects to DB. Objects are added in HashSet during particular Hibernate session. When I add an equal object to the one which is already in DB it happens in new Hibernate session with new empty HashSet.